# Need a 1.8V to 5V enable circuit

Tags: mosfet, analog, arm

I have an ARM board which uses a VIO of 1.8V .I need to use one of the ARM pin as enable to other device that need to enable with 5V.
How i can do it with this FET( i prefer to use this one cuse he is small and i already used him in other place in my board).
[enter link description here](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FD/FDN327N.pdf)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Typical Common Emitter/Common Source circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fymKFq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the GPIO is high, the Enable pin is pulled to ground through the Mosfet. When GPIO is low, the Enable pin is pulled high through R2. Size your resistors appropriately.

Comment: Note that if you want it to be non-inverting, you can chain one more of the exact same thing to get your 5V output to follow your 1.8V input.

Comment: uh, that's not a follower that's an inverter, with gain

Comment: @passerby how did you determine the resistors value?

Comment: For this low input logic level, a few words about MOSFET selection might be appropriate.

Comment: Op already has a 1.8 v mosfet available.

Comment: @jasen your right. It was a common source setup not emitter follower. Updated.

Comment: I would suggest to use a much larger pullup (R2). Maybe around 100k. But 10k at least. Just to make sure it turns on. Vgs is specified at ID = 250 uA. So ID may not be all that large. Personally, I would use a BJT for this, but I believe the FET will work.